# issue while deleting columns in cassandra using hector api

Tags: cassandra, hector

Hi im new to cassandra and hector api im trying crud operations while im trying to delete the particular column its not deleting still exists on the table(backend java). please help me out.

```
Cluster  cluster =  HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("TestCluster", new CassandraHostConfigurator("localhost:9160")); 
         Keyspace keyspace  = HFactory.createKeyspace("sometext", cluster);
         Mutator<String> mutator  = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, StringSerializer.get()); 
         mutator.delete(key, "user2", "first", StringSerializer.get());
         mutator.execute();
```

Comment: "Still exists" - Do you mean the db files & folders under cassandra-data or it exists in cassandra-cli?

Do you get any error when deleting?

You don't have to worry about the folders still present.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I was just trying to delete the left space in the table after delete operation. Later by document i came to know its a natural behavior of Cassandra (tombstone issue).